# Material list does not scroll in mobile devices

Tags: angular-material, user-experience

I am using [mat-list](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview) and I can't scroll it on mobile devices.

It is a mat-nav-list with some mat-list-item inside, the structure of my list is something like:

```
<mat-nav-list>
   <a mat-list-item matTooltip="dashboard" routerLink="/dashboard">
     <mat-icon matListIcon>dashboard</mat-icon>
   </a>
   ...
</mat-nav-list>
```

I can scroll normally in desktop with the mouse but when I am in a mobile browser I see every mat-list-item with this:

```
element.style {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  touch-action: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Is the browser applies that CSS itself?
If I try to override with inline style nothing change, how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?
From you description it's not clear what should be scrollable - the parent container? A single list item? What do you mean "in a mobile browser"? Are you using chrome with emulation options or something else?

Comment: every item is just an icon as you can see, I need to scroll the entire list.
for mobile browser I mean in a smartphone ( not emulation or something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, the CSS style came from `mat-list-item`.
So the only thing I can do is to override it directly.

```
[mat-list-item]{
  touch-action: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Also works on mat-cell.....if you happen to be styling a table to look like a list on small view ports.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bug that happen when you add a `matTooltip`, see this ticket here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4892

So another solution would be to remove the tooltip if possible...
There are also others possibles workarounds in the ticket.